# how to get the absolute position of loaded .obj in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, .obj

loading the .obj:

```
        loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( objMesh ) {
                objMesh.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                       child.material = mat2;
                }
            } );
```

I tried to find the position with mrdoobs code:

```
objMesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

var boundingBox = objMesh.geometry.boundingBox;

var position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.subVectors( boundingBox.max, boundingBox.min );
position.multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
position.add( boundingBox.min );

position.applyMatrix4( objMesh.matrixWorld );

alert(position.x + ',' + position.y + ',' + position.z);
```

however this fails with

```
objMesh.geometry is undefined
```

Is this not possible with loaded meshes?

Comment: Where you create the _Mesh_ _object_?

Comment: I used a little modified version if this example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

Comment: You can check on _objMesh_ object creation if it is not `null` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but in your case seems that the `objMesh` is a local variable in the scope of `function ( objMesh ) {...}`.

So you can declare a global variable, let's say `mesh` and then set its value inside the `onLoad` callback function

```
var mesh;
...
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( objMesh ) {
            objMesh.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                   child.material = mat2;
                   mesh = child; // set value to the global variable, applicable, if the objMesh has one child of THREE.Mesh()
            }

        } );
```

and then apply mrdoob's code to the `mesh` variable, not the `objMesh`.

Or, you can wrap mrdoob's code in a function and then call this function in the callback `onLoad` function with a parameter of your mesh:

```
function absPos( myMesh ){
    myMesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    var boundingBox = myMesh.geometry.boundingBox;

    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.subVectors( boundingBox.max, boundingBox.min );
    position.multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
    position.add( boundingBox.min );

    position.applyMatrix4( myMesh.matrixWorld );

    alert(position.x + ',' + position.y + ',' + position.z);
}
```

calling it in the callback function

```
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( objMesh ) {
            objMesh.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                   child.material = mat2;
                   absPos( child ); // call our function
            }

        } );
```

Comment: Hmm doesn´t seem to be the solution. To avoid own mistakes I just took the example from three.js https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html , added the function and absPos(object) below scene.add( object ); result: TypeError: myMesh.geometry is undefined

Comment: yeah, my fault. I've updated the answer. `objMesh` is an `object`, whose children are of `THREE.Mesh()`, and of course the `object` doesn't have the `geometry` property.

Comment: uhm, nope not yet, remains myMesh.geometry is undefined pointing at myMesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); I assume the children don´t have a three.js typical geometry if imported from an .obj but thats just a guess

Comment: as an option, you can `console.log(myMesh)` and see in the browser console what your object consists of.

Comment: as I expected there is no geometry in the object so this BoundingBox thing won´t work here, I guess have to go deeper into the objloader